# Jquery append if location finish with W12345

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

I need to do a conditional append here is the example `url`

```
www.google.com/default.asp/W12345
```

I want to append a `JS` file if the `url` has `W` and a random string of numbers after it.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<script>
  if (/default\.asp\/W[\d\w]*$/.test(location.href)) {
    document.write("<script src='/path/to/your/js/file.js'>");
  }
</script>
```

Insert that code anywhere on the page, typically either in the head, either at the very end of the document.

Comment: `document.write` will replace the whole content of current document. Instead add it as a DOM.

Comment: I believe it will just add it do the DOM. Actually, I've tested this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below snippet on `dom-loaded`. Here I'm making use of regular expression if it ends with url */wSomeString* or */WsomeOtherString*.

```
if(/.+\/w.+$/i.test(window.location.href)) {
    var scriptDom = document.createElement("script");
    scriptDom.type = "application/javascript";
    scriptDom.src = "url/to/js";                   //update JS url here.
    document.body.appendChild(scriptDom);
}
```